# What is wrong with my Typescript AngularJS 1.5 component?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-components

I need a custom AngularJS 1.5x component (in TypeScript!) for entering a date and time, that will have some required time zone correction logic, like this:

```
<date-time value="vm.woComplete.CompleteDate"></date-time>
```

where `vm.woComplete.CompleteDate` is the date property of my data model.

TypeScript code for this component is this:

```
namespace AppDomain {
    "use strict";

    export class DateTimeComponent {

        require: string = "ngModel";
        bindings: any = { value: "=" };
        template: string = "<input type='date' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'><input type='time' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'></p>";

        controller: Function = function ($scope) {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.$onInit = function () {
                console.log(arguments);
                ctrl.displayValue = new Date(ctrl.value);
                ctrl.displayValue.setHours(ctrl.displayValue.getHours() - 4);
            }

            $scope.$watch('$ctrl.displayValue', function () {
                var tmpDate = new Date(ctrl.displayValue);
                ctrl.value = tmpDate.setHours(tmpDate.getHours() + 4);
            });
        }

    }

    app.component("dateTime", DateTimeComponent);

}
```

**But I don't get any output. What am I doing wrong?**

I want to have proper TypeScript code with `$onInit` and `$onChanges`instead of `$scope.$watch`.

Here is the example, just need to convert it TypeScript!

http://plnkr.co/edit/D9Oi6le7G9i3hNC2yvqy?p=preview

Comment: Do you have the JavaScript this file produces linked in your HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a syntax I have never seen, and what is `DetailController`?
Try with this syntax instead:

```
export class Controller {
    value: number;
    displayValue: Date;

    $onInit() {
        this.displayValue = new Date(this.value);
        this.displayValue.setHours(this.displayValue.getHours() - 4);
    };

    $onChanges() {
        const tmpDate = new Date(this.displayValue);
        this.value = tmpDate.setHours(tmpDate.getHours() + 4);
    };
}
const component : angular.IComponentOptions = {
    controller : Controller,
    bindings: { value: "=" },
    template: `
        <p><label>Date:</label><br>
        <input type='date' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'></p>
        <p><label>Time:</label><br>
        <input type='time' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'></p>`

};
app.component("dateTime", component);
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code and this post with your fix, but it still doesnt show, component script is attached, but when I add alert('bla bla bla') inside $onInit(), I dont get a popup, so it is not being called

Comment: @monstro: I have change my answer

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am just confused about how to implement angular component in typescript... ;(

Comment: I have add some type annotations to be more TypeScript, but basically, that's it!